# How can i identify self.editButtonItem button's clicked event?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I set my left bar button of UINavigationController as edit button using the code

```
leftBarButton = self.editButtonItem;
```

I want to change some disable/enable properties of other buttons with respect to the edit button's click action.

How can i find whether the Edit button is pressed or not?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The edit button's action sends your view controller the `setEditing:animated` message. Override this in your subclass to perform other actions when entering or leaving edit mode.

Be sure to call the `super` implementation at the end to manage the rest of the transition to editing view.

Comment: Thanks for your information... But, if i use the `setEditing:animated` method, the animations & the red color minus button did't appear

Comment: You have to call `[super setEditing:editing animated:animated]` at the end of your override.

Answer (score 19):

So finally i got the solution...

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if(editing) {
        //Do something for edit mode
    }

    else {
        //Do something for non-edit mode
    }

}
```

This method will be called with out changing the original behavior of `self.editButtonItem` button.

Comment: The second method should never be used.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   ....
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    // Toggles the edit button state
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    // Toggles the actual editing actions appearing on a table view
    tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift you can follow the below methods:**

```
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
    }

   override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool){

        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)


    }
```

Comment: seriously, an `if (editing)` branch when you could have just said `tableView.setEditing(editing, animation: animated)` and have it work for both cases ?

Comment: it works but technically u are correct thanks for suggestion

Comment: Works nicely on UITableView inside UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBut=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(doSomething)];


self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=barBut;

[barBut release];


.h
-(void)doSomething;

.m 

-(void)doSomething{

    NSLog(@"dooooooooooooo");
        //ur stuff
}
```

updated:

```
 - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

will be called

```
editButtonItem

Returns a bar button item that toggles its title and associated state between Edit and Done.

- (UIBarButtonItem *)editButtonItem

Discussion
If one of the custom views of the navigationItem property is set to the returned object, the associated navigation bar displays an Edit button if editing is NO and a Done button if editing is YES. The default button action invokes the setEditing:animated: method.

    Availability
    Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

    See Also
    @property editing

    – setEditing:animated:


    Declared In
    UIViewController.h
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks vijay.. But i want to know the scenario for self.editButtonItem button