# How to know that no row is selected in my UITableView?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, selection, uisplitviewcontroller

I use a `UITableView` to display a list of items, and when a row is selected I show that item in a detail view next to it (using a split view controller).

As the selection in the table view changes I want my detail view to change as well, which is of course standard behavior and it works flawlessly... except when no row is selected anymore in the table view.

Users can for example delete a row from the table view, and during and also after that deletion there will be no selected row in the table view. Of course after a row is deleted I let my detail view controller know, but during the editing process in the table view, when no row is selected, my detail view controller does not know this.

I tried to use the `UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` but that only gets sent when the user selects a different row, not when a deselection occurs.

How can I be notified of the fact that the table view switches from having a row selected to having no selection at all?

EDIT:

As a temporary solution, I tried renaming the Edit-button to "Reorder" and only allowing moving rows from A to B but without allowing the deletion controls, but this can not be done, there is no move control without enabling editing on a row. The thing is, I do get a pointer to a row that is up for moving, so I can keep that selected. I do not get this pointer for a row up for deletion, so no go for me. I always want to know what row a user works on, and keep that row selected at all times.

I may have to resort to ditching the standard editing behavior and adding my own buttons and methods for it. Or see what gestures can do for me to capture touches on any row...

Comment: the deletion is the only case where a row is not selected?

Comment: I already catch the situation after the user adds a new row, in this case I select the row programmatically and let the detail view know.
But entering Edit-mode or swiping over a row to start deleting it deselects any previously selected row and yes, that must be handled.
I also want to select the row below or above the recently deleted row, but that is my next goal, I first need to handle any deselected state of the table view and I wish there was a notification for this.

Answer (score 3):

There is a property `indexPathForSelectedRow`.  I'm not sure what it would return when there is no selected row, but it may return nil or something like that, which you could use as a trigger to know if there are any rows selected.  Something like

```
if (myTable.indexPathForSelectedRow == nil)
{
  //do something here to account for no rows being selected
}
else
{
  //do stuff here to set up your detail view
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you, this property is indeed nil when no row is selected, but I have to be the one to trigger asking it, as the table view does not notify me of such a change. Deselecting a row is not enough for the notification to be sent.

Comment: hmm, there's also an optional UITableViewDelegate method `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath`.  The code in that method will get triggered everytime a cell gets deselected.  I'm not sure if the code in my above answer will work, because the cell my still be selected at that point, but if you're looking to just not display anything in your detail view whenever the user is editing the table, you could just put the code to clear out the detail view right inside this method.  Hmm... is that clear? I can post a new answer with the example code if you want.

Comment: EDIT: `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` will be triggered every time the user starts editing a cell, not every time the cell is deselected.

Answer (score 0):

How are you implementing the deletion of rows? Are you implementing the following data source method?

> tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:

You can have a property like

> NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath

and set it to nil when a row is being deleted.

Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   //select another row in your table
   [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:*indexPathOfTheRowToBeSelected* animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
   //then delete row from data source
}
```

The method above will be called when the user touches the delete button on the table he/she has selected to delete.

Comment: I can handle deletions using your suggestion, but I want to be notified of the swipe-to-delete first so that I can immediately select the row the user swiped over. Standard behavior deselects any row while deleting, and I never want to leave my table view in a deselected state for as long as there are still rows in it.

Comment: Can you not select another row, say your table's first row, in commitEditingStyle before deleting the row selected? You can select another row using UITableView's selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:

Comment: commitEditingStyle is only called when the user confirms the deletion, not when he first swipes a row to delete it (or presses the minus sign in front of a row). So I have no pointer to a row up for deletion until it actually gets deleted, which for me is too late.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand why you need to change the selected row while the cell is in editing mode. However, you can find out if a cell is in the 'editing' mode inquiring the UITableviewCell's 'editing' BOOL property. If the property is set to YES it means that the user has swiped and editing the cell. You could observe the value of the 'editing' property i guess..

Comment: I always want to have one row selected, and I always want to draw its details in the detail view controller, even when editing in the master view controller's table view. Or, if that is not possible or desired after all, at least I want to be notified of the fact that there is currently no row selected at all.
I will look into observing the entering and exiting of the edit mode, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I misread what you were asking at first, I'm pretty sure what you want is either  `– tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` or `– tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`.  These methods will be triggered automatically when the user deselects a row (either right before the row is deselected or right after, respectively).  Implement one of these in your table view delegates code, and you'll know whenever a row gets deselected, and you can put your code to select the next row or whatever you want in one of these methods.

Comment: This and other stuff did not work at all, until I found out that my master view controller was not explicitly told to behave as the `UITableViewDelegate`. It is a `UITableViewController` so I did not think I'd have to tell it more but for certain calls, for example your suggestion, it seems to make a difference. NOW I can really start testing :)

Comment: When having one row selected and the user pressing another one, `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` is being triggered. Unfortunately when entering deletion mode by swiping across a row the currently selected row is deselected without `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` being called, so still no go...

Comment: Really?  Well that's entirely unintuitive.  Thanks Apple.  Same for `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` I take it?

Comment: Both are not being triggered when entering Edit mode, either by pushing the Edit button or by swiping across a row :(

Comment: It probably leaves one solution: subclassing the table view cell and handling the swipe myself (but that does not account yet for the Edit button).

Comment: as I mentioned in my other answer, there's a method that gets triggered whenever editing begins, and yet another for deleting cells.  You would have to have code in each of these methods, instead of all in one method (or you could have the delegate methods both call some method you would write to handle the deleting, so that you don't have to maintain the code in 2 separate spots). That's still a PitA though.

Comment: After all these hours of trying I will go through the PITA to fix it once and for all. If I can make it work, I will post it here.

Comment: Ha I know what you mean.  I've been getting those delegate methods from [the Apple Docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate), and [this Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView) maybe be helpful too.  You might end up needing to implement some others as well for other situations that might not have been seen yet.

Comment: I subclassed my table view cells and using `didTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state` I now see what I want, namely the swiping action and entering the editing mode for each cell. Now I just have to call back to my table view to do the right thing, I guess. Will post more if I am done...

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well. Turns out that when the "Edit" button is hit, all rows are deselected at that point. You can override setEditing:animated: to detect when it is hit, but you must call [super setEditing:editing animated:animated] before you return.

See this link for where I found this:

[How can i identify self.editButtonItem button's clicked event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334126/how-can-i-identify-self-editbuttonitem-buttons-clicked-event)